# Serving an array of different content types in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3.2, helpermethods

I have two content types, articles and events. I want to create a partial on my homepage to serve an array of both.

I was thinking of creating a helper method called latest_news, something like this

```
def latest_news(limit=12)
    @articles = Article.all
    @events = Event.all
    sort_by(&:created_at)
end
```

Also, how would I sort the articles by their publish_date and the events by their event_date?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to put it in helper method? You can have @articles and @events in your controller action which is serving home page.

Also you can sort individually both the content

@articles = Article.order(:publish_date)

@events = Event.order(:event_date)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your suggestion - do you mean to say put this in a defined method inside the homepage controller?

Comment: Yes.. I understand from your post that you want to show articles and events in your home page so whatever action which is defined for home page can execute above queries

Comment: How would you handle the array in the partial to show things between the two content types? For instance, events have a location where articles do not

Comment: I assume that you are having separate partials for both events and articles so you will be using relevant objects and details accordingly

Check this out

http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/61-simplify-render-in-views

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Comment: No, I have a single partial for both. I want to have an array that returns both articles and events within that partial.